# How do I correctly write a CSV file on individual rows and columns?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, io

I am producing a small recipe input and output program in **Python**, however I am having trouble writing the ingredients to a **CSV** file. I am trying to print each item of a list to a comma separated file, using this code:

```
with open('recipes/' + recipeName + '.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    recipewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    recipewriter.write(ingredientList[0])
    recipewriter.write(ingredientList[1])
    recipewriter.write(ingredientList[2])
```

In the list, there are three items. For example, this could be a list I am trying to save to a file:

```
ingredientList = ['flour', '500', 'g']
```

And I want the data to appear like this in a CSV file:

```
flour,
500,
g,
```

Instead it is appearing like this:

```
f,l,o,u,r,
5,0,0,
g,
```

How do I get it to appear in my desired format?

Here is my source code:

```
#Python 3.3.3

import sys #Allows use of the 'exit()' function
import csv #Allows use of the CSV File API

def mainMenu():
    print("########################################################")
    print("# Welcome to the recipe book, please select an option: #")
    print("# 1. Add new recipe                                    #")
    print("# 2. Lookup existing recipe                            #")
    print("# 3. Exit                                              #")
    print("########################################################")

    selectedOption = None
    inputtedOption = input()

    try:
        inputtedOption = int(inputtedOption)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid option entered")

    if inputtedOption == 1:
        selectedOption = inputtedOption
    elif inputtedOption == 2:
        selectedOption = inputtedOption
    elif inputtedOption == 3:
        print("Exiting...")
        sys.exit(0)

    return selectedOption

def validateInput(inputtedData):
    try: #Test if data is an integer greater than 1
        inputtedData = int(inputtedData)
        if int(inputtedData) < 1: #Recipes cannot contain less than 1 ingredient
            print("Sorry, invalid data entered.\n('%s' is not valid for this value - positive integers only)" % inputtedData)
            return False
        return int(inputtedData)
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, invalid data entered.\n('%s' is not valid for this value - whole integers only [ValueError])\n" % inputtedData)
        return False

def addRecipe():
    print("Welcome to recipe creator! The following questions will guide you through the recipe creation process.\nPlease enter the name of your recipe (e.g. 'Pizza'):")
    recipeName = input()
    print("Recipe Name: %s" % recipeName)
    print("Please enter the amount of people this recipe serves (e.g. '6'):")
    recipeServingAmount = input()
    if validateInput(recipeServingAmount) == False:
        return
    else:
        recipeServingAmount = validateInput(recipeServingAmount)
    print("Recipe serves: %s" % recipeServingAmount)
    print("Please enter the number of ingredients in this recipe (e.g. '10'):")
    recipeNumberOfIngredients = input()
    if validateInput(recipeNumberOfIngredients) == False:
        return
    else:
        recipeNumberOfIngredients = validateInput(recipeNumberOfIngredients)
    print("Recipe contains: %s different ingredients" % recipeNumberOfIngredients)
    ingredientList = {}
    i = 1
    while i <= recipeNumberOfIngredients:
        nthFormat = "st"
        if i == 2:
            nthFormat = "nd"
        elif i == 3:
            nthFormat = "rd"
        elif i >= 4:
            nthFormat = "th"
        ingredientNumber = str(i) + nthFormat
        print("Please enter the name of the %s ingredient:" % ingredientNumber)
        ingredientName = input()
        print("Please enter the quantity of the %s ingredient:" % ingredientNumber)
        ingredientQuantity = input()
        print("Please enter the measurement value for the %s ingredient (leave blank for no measurement - e.g. eggs):"  % ingredientNumber)
        ingredientMeasurement = input()
        print("%s ingredient: %s%s %s" % (ingredientNumber, ingredientQuantity, ingredientMeasurement, ingredientName))
        finalIngredient = [ingredientName, ingredientQuantity, ingredientMeasurement]
        print(finalIngredient[1])
        ingredientList[i] = finalIngredient
        with open('recipes/' + recipeName + '.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            recipewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            recipewriter.write(ingredientList[0])
            recipewriter.write(ingredientList[1])
            recipewriter.write(ingredientList[2])

        i = i + 1

def lookupRecipe():
    pass  # To-do: add CSV reader and string formatter

#Main flow of program
while True:
    option = mainMenu()

    if option == 1:
        addRecipe()
    elif option == 2:
        lookupRecipe()
```

Comment: While you can generate a text file containing `"flour,\n500,\ng,\n"` (several answers show how), be aware that's poor CSV structure. Related data is scattered amongst several rows, and the trailing commas suggest a (missing) second column.

Answer (score 2):

`csv.writer`s don't have a `write()` method. In Python 3 you could do it like this:

```
with open('recipes/' + recipeName + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    recipewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    recipewriter.writerow([ingredientList[0]])
    recipewriter.writerow([ingredientList[1]])
    recipewriter.writerow([ingredientList[2]])
```

Comment: I seem to be getting KeyError: 0 when I try this block of code

Comment: The means the _dictionary_ `ingredientList` doesn't have an entry in it for one of the three keys you're trying to access — `0`, `1`, or `2` — depending upon exactly which `writerow()` line the `KeyError` occurs on. You could try `print(ingredientList)` before then and see exactly what's in it (and maybe also why it's not what you expected).

Comment: As I metioned, in your actual code `ingredientList` is a dictionary not a list. The `KeyError` is because you never put anything in `ingredientList[0]` because you initialize `i = 1` before the `while` loop. One way to fix that would be to use `ingredientList[1]`, `[2]`, and `[3]`. Another problem I noticed is that you're rewriting the whole file each time through the loop — so, for example, if there were 4 different ingredients in the recipe, only the last one will end up in the file. Therefore I would move the opening of the file and the creation of the `csv.writer` out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to just call join on the list adding a `,` and a newline and forget about using the csv module:

```
with open('recipes/{}.csv'.format(recipeName), 'w') as csvfile:
        csvfile.write(",\n".join(ingredientList))
```

Output:

```
flour,
500,
g
```

I presume you are actually using `writerow` not write as `csv.writer` has no write method.

The reason you see `f,l,o,u,r,` is because `csv.writer.writerow` expects an iterable so when you pass the string it iterates over and writes each character individually.

You would need to use `recipewriter.writerow([ingredientList[0]])`, wrapping the string in a list.

That  will still not  actually  add any trailing comma after the end of your strings.

If you want a trailing comma after each line including the last:

```
with open('recipes/{}.csv'.format("foo"), 'w') as csvfile:
    for ele in ingredientList:
         csvfile.write("{},\n".format(ele))
```

Output:

```
flour,
500,
g,
```

If you want a useful csv you may be better making each it's own column or just writing each to  their own line:

```
import csv
with open('{}.csv'.format("foo"), 'w') as csvfile:
    recipewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    recipewriter.writerow(ingredientList)
```

Output:

```
flour,500,g
```

Or on individual lines without  the trailing comma:

```
with open('{}.csv'.format("foo"), 'w') as csvfile:
    recipewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for ele in ingredientList:
         recipewriter.writerow([ele])
```

Output:

```
flour
500
g
```